# Intro to Manifolds, Lang Definition

Tags: linear-algebra, manifolds

On p6 of Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds by Lang:

[image]

I don't see how "this amounts..." Is $\phi$ even linear?

Answer (score 0):

> Is $\phi$ even linear?

No. Why should it be?

> I don't see how "this amounts..."

That's just the definition of the notation $o(t)W$, when you have a norm to use.

Perhaps it will help if you should keep in mind that, for the map $\varphi$ to be **tangent to 0** means roughly that $\varphi$ is **differentiable** at $0\in \mathbf{E}$ and that $\varphi'(0) = 0$. Compare both notations then to the usual one when this is true.